# Releasing ORMLite helper on @Singleton

Tags: android, guice, ormlite, roboguice

I have a `@Singleton` class where I've injected an instance of `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`. Do I actually ever need to call the `OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper()`? In case I do, where and how should it be done as the class doesn't extend any Android base class where I could get to the `onDestroy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) example Android project which demonstrates this called [HelloAndroidNoBase](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/).  I'd check it out.

The relevant code section from the main `Activity` is included below.  You'll need to have this sort of code in each one of your `Activity` or other classes that uses the database.

If your class does not have an `onDestroy()` method then you need to add one and call it from one of the other classes that does have `onDestroy()`.  The main `Activity` is a good place for this.  So your `MainActivity.onDestroy()` would call `yourClass.onDestroy()` when the application is shutting down.

```
public class HelloNoBase extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (databaseHelper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            databaseHelper = null;
        }
    }

    private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (databaseHelper == null) {
            databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this,
                DatabaseHelper.class);
        }
        return databaseHelper;
    }
}
```