# Ormlite for Android, worth releasing the helper?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

As recommended, I'm using a singleton for acquiring the helper (I'm assuring it is first created on the onCreate() of my application, using the application context).

This helper is then used from different [Intent]Services, but I'm confused about releasing : I already read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068634/releasing-ormlite-helper-on-singleton), but the ormlite's documentation about `releaseHelper()` seems contradictory:

> WARNING: This should be called in an onDestroy() type of method when your application or service is terminating or if your code is no longer going to use the helper or derived DAOs in any way. *Don't* call this method if you expect to call {@link #getHelper(Context)} again before the application terminates.

The second part of the warning above is telling to NOT call releaseHelper() if we're expecting to call getHelper() again before the application terminates, which will be more than likely the case if another service is fired up BEFORE the application's process terminates!

Moreover, according to [this post](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection), not releasing the helper sounds safe on Android.

Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree on the confusion.

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android states to call OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper() on each Activity/Fragment's onDestroy(), yet the warning comment on releaseHelper() clearly tells you to only use it when the *Application* terminates.

Perhaps the warning in releaseHelper() comments are no longer relevant?  And [Kevin Galligan's warning post](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection) is also no longer relevant due to changes after his departure from the project?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I misunderstanding?

Not sure if you are understanding or not.

Once the database has been closed, which happens when the `DatabaseHelper` is released by the last part of your application, it cannot be re-opened.  The warning is there just to make sure that if some background task works with the database, it should *not* ask for the helper *after* the final call to `releaseHelper()` has been made.  If you have background tasks then they should get the helper and hold it until the task finishes.

Comment: I am confused with this javadoc as well. OpenHelperManager counts how many times getHelper() was called. And releaseHelper() checks if this count is positive or if it has reached zero usages finally. So for every get I need one release otherwise this condition will never happen. This is fine for activities with onCreate and onDestroy pairs. But if I will use getHelper with App context in other classes I shall call releaseHelper in finally block, shall I not?

Comment: I think the best way is to use one helper in every activity, close it in `onDestroy`. And get another helper in every worker thread, close it in `finally` block. But I'm not quite understanding the `cannot be re-opened` part. Does it mean that I can't open and close a `DatabaseHelper` twice in one block? What happened if we call `getHelper` again when the reference count is zero?